# Исправить контекст SessionListener

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста исправить SessionListener, необходимо сделать следующее:
 - в листенере не нужны поля;
 - в листенере использовать контекст сессии, а не сервлета.

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
DAOFactory daoFactory = new DAOFactory();
ServletContext context = null;
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    context = event.getSession().getServletContext();
    try {
        context.setAttribute("connection", daoFactory.getProfileDAO());
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    try {
        daoFactory.getProfileDAO().close();
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Видимо вас просят сделать метод `getProfileDAO()` статическим, и сохранять получившийся объект как атрибут сессии, а не сервлета.

Comment: статику нельзя использовать, переписал вот так (не уверен, код ниже)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание сессии для пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543295/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        DAOFactory daoFactory = new DAOFactory();
        try {
            event.getSession().setAttribute("connection", daoFactory.getProfileDAO());
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        ProfileDAO instance = (ProfileDAO) event.getSession().getAttribute("connection");
        try {
            instance.close();
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.